# DocuSign Client Api composite template using tabs

Tags: docusignapi

When building our envelope, we use the templateId (ID1), and then add other server template (ID2) by using the composite template.  I add all of the appropriate tab fields for the main template (ID1) and the server (ID2) to the envelope.  But after I submit the request, the tabs for the main template (ID1) show up and are populated, but the tabs for the server template (ID2) are not showing and the values are missing.

We are using DocuSigns [client API](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/DocuSign).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Just a tip -- you're more likely to get constructive feedback if you post the code that you're using to create the envelope.  Hard to say where you're going wrong without seeing the request you're submitting to DocuSign.  (You can edit your original post to add your code -- be sure to obfuscate any sensitive information in the request data.)

Comment: I was able to figure this out.  I added a recipient, signer, and tabs to the server/inlinetemplate it self.